# use shapefile to mask raster data in ArcGIS, then weighted sum

Tags: arcgis

I want to mask a raster data using a shapefile with ArcGIS, then weighted sum the masked parts.

Following is the path of the tool I used.

Spatial Analysis Tool -> Extraction -> Extract by mask.

When I use this tool to realize my intention, I always get several grids. However, what I want is an output having the same shape as my shapefile.
I hope the output includes several parts and can be weighted sum.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a coding site. For questions like this I would try https://gis.stackexchange.com/ instead.

I am not sure what you mean with `weighted sum` in this context, but here is an example of what you can do with R

Example data

```
library(raster)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))[1,]
r <- raster(extent(p)+2, vals=1:100)
plot(x)
plot(p, add=T)
```

Raster cropped to polygon

```
x <- crop(r, p)
plot(x)
plot(p, add=T)
```

Disaggregate cells so that they fit the polygon better, followdd by crop and mask

```
d <- disaggregate(r, 100)
x <- crop(d, p)
m <- mask(x, p)
plot(m)
plot(p, add=T)
```